# How to add tzinfo to date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I have the following vars:

`time_created = datetime.utcnow()` and `time_created_day = datetime.utcnow().date()`.

I cannot save `time_created_day` to the db because of `AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'`

How to fix this (add `tzinfo`)?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to save the date as if it were a datetime. What's the type of the database column you're trying to save the date in?

Comment: The type is `UTCDateTimeAttribute` Im using db orm (pynamodb)

Comment: Why are you trying to store a date where a datetime is expected?

Comment: The reason why I'm trying to store `datetime.utcnow().date()` that `time_created_day ` must contain only year,month and day. Do you know how can I get datetime object that will represent current `year,month and day`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is one way that I did this.

If you need to add tzinfo, you may use the below.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
  time_created_day = datetime.datetime.utcnow().date()
  time_created_day_with_tz_info = datetime(time_created_day.year, 
  time_created_day.month, time_created_day.day, tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC'))


 > print time_created_day_with_tz_info

 > datetime.datetime(2018, 5, 9, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```